# Film/series where a spaceship discovers a planet that periodically disappears and time passes much faster

Tags: story-identification, movie

A couple(?) of crew are on board a spaceship. One of them is a robot.

They find a planet that disappears periodically and reappears and changes drastically. Unbeknownst to the locals, they go down to the planet and a woman in the crew of the spaceship heals an injured person with a device. The civilisation praises them and executes many people in her name.

The robot is sent to stay on the planet to see where it goes for the time it is gone. It says something like "*What is for you 500 years, is for me a blink of an eye*" or something like that

When then planet reappears, the civilisation is more advanced than the crew of the spaceship and they realises that woman was not a god.

<sub>Note. It's definitely not Star Trek: Voyager (Blink of an Eye) although there are *some* parallels</sub>

Comment: There's a disappearing / reappearing planet in the DS9 episode "Meridian" and Jadzia Dax is featured in it. But does not meet all the criteria.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That would be [The Orville season 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Orville_(season_1)) episode ["Mad Idolatry"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5943640/). The character left behind was Isaac (who isn't exactly a robot - there's a complex reveal spanning numerous season 1 & 2 episodes). It does share some plot points with the [Start Trek Deep Space 9 episodes "Children of Time"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Children_of_Time_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) and ["Meridian"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meridian_(Star_Trek:_Deep_Space_Nine)) but the points concerning the healing and character left behind are unique to the Orville story. For that matter, all these stories share plot points with the fantasy story ["Brigadoon"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brigadoon_(film)).

Comment: Also elements of TNG's 'Who Watches the Watchers'.

Comment: That episode bugged me as Isaac was a witness to all of the advancements made over the span of his time on the planet, which ended up well in advance of the Orville,  yet he never seems to share any of what he has witnessed.

Comment: Also the link to the Orville episode refers to [Voyager: Blink of an eye](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0708856/?ref_=tt_trv_trv)

Comment: @PeterM Well, when we find out more about Isaac his lack of interest in their tech makes more sense

Comment: The OP mentions thinking Kelly is a goddess (the kid had an incredible memory for faces!) The Orville episode had a strong old Star Trek examining-religion theme. The DS:9 Children of Time episode was just generic Back-To-The-Future alternate timelines stuff. It felt completely different.

Comment: @OwenReynolds Don't forget that Seth MacFarlane is/has long been a big fan of Star Trek, and he created The Orville largely as an homage, so it should come as no surprise that classic elements of Trek would appear in his show.

Comment: @AnthonyX Homage, spoof, something in between maybe.  Started as a joke ay least, ended up being more Star Trek than actual Star Trek, when compared to *Discovery* or *Picard* or even the J.J. Abrams movies.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Given Seth MacFarlane's sense of humor as it manifests in series like Family Guy, I'd say that no matter how spoofy The Orville ever was or will be, it always was and always will be a Seth MacFarlane homage .